# In R, how to make the variables inside a function available to the lower level function inside this function?(with, attach, environment)

Tags: r, function, environment-variables, with-statement, assign

**Update 2**
@G. Grothendieck posted two approaches. The second one is changing the function environment inside a function. This solves my problem of too many coding replicates. I am not sure if this is a good method to pass through the CRAN check when making my scripts into a package. I will update again when I have some conclusions.

**Update**

I am trying to pass a lot of input argument variables to `f2` and do not want to index every variable inside the function as `env$c, env$d, env$calls`, that is why I tried to use `with` in `f5` and `f6`(a modified `f2`). However, `assign` does not work with `with` inside the `{}`, moving `assign` outside `with` will do the job but in my real case I have a few `assign`s inside the `with` expressions which I do not know how to move them out of the `with` function easily.

Here is an example:

```
## In the <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
a <- 1
b <- 2
f1 <- function(){
    c <- 3
d <- 4
f2 <- function(P){
    assign("calls", calls+1, inherits=TRUE)
    print(calls)
    return(P+c+d)
 }
calls <- 0
v <- vector()
for(i in 1:10){
    v[i] <- f2(P=0)
    c <- c+1
    d <- d+1
  }
 return(v)
}
f1()
```

Function `f2` is inside `f1`, when `f2` is called, it looks for variables `calls,c,d` in the environment `environment(f1)`. This is what I wanted.

However, when I want to use `f2` also in the other functions, I will define this function in the Global environment instead, call it `f4`.

```
f4 <- function(P){
  assign("calls", calls+1, inherits=TRUE)
  print(calls)
  return(P+c+d)
}
```

This won't work, because it will look for `calls,c,d` in the Global environment instead of inside a function where the function is called. For example:

```
f3 <- function(){
  c <- 3
  d <- 4
  calls <- 0
  v <- vector()
  for(i in 1:10){
    v[i] <- f4(P=0) ## or replace here with f5(P=0)
    c <- c+1
    d <- d+1
  }
  return(v)
}
f3()
```

The safe way should be define `calls,c,d` in the input arguments of `f4` and then pass these parameters into `f4`. However, in my case, there are too many variables to be passed into this function `f4` and it would be better that I can pass it as an environment and tell `f4` do not look in the Global environment(`environment(f4)`), only look inside the `environment` when `f3` is called.

The way I solve it now is to use the environment as a list and use the `with` function.

```
f5 <- function(P,liste){
  with(liste,{
     assign("calls", calls+1, inherits=TRUE)
     print(calls)
     return(P+c+d)
     }
  )
}
f3 <- function(){
  c <- 3
  d <- 4
  calls <- 0
  v <- vector()
  for(i in 1:10){
    v[i] <- f5(P=0,as.list(environment())) ## or replace here with f5(P=0)
    c <- c+1
    d <- d+1
  }
  return(v)
}
f3()
```

However, now `assign("calls", calls+1, inherits=TRUE)` does not work as it should be since `assign` does not modify the original object. The variable `calls` is connected to an optimization function where the objective function is `f5`. That is the reason I use `assign` instead of passing `calls` as an input arguments. Using `attach` is also not clear to me. Here is my way to correct the `assign` issue:

```
f7 <- function(P,calls,liste){
  ##calls <<- calls+1
  ##browser()
  assign("calls", calls+1, inherits=TRUE,envir = sys.frame(-1))
  print(calls)
  with(liste,{
    print(paste('with the listed envrionment, calls=',calls))
    return(P+c+d)
  }
  )
}
########
##################
f8 <- function(){
  c <- 3
  d <- 4
  calls <- 0
  v <- vector()
  for(i in 1:10){
    ##browser()
    ##v[i] <- f4(P=0) ## or replace here with f5(P=0)
    v[i] <- f7(P=0,calls,liste=as.list(environment()))
    c <- c+1
    d <- d+1
  }
  f7(P=0,calls,liste=as.list(environment()))
  print(paste('final call number',calls))
  return(v)
}
f8()
```

I am not sure how this should be done in R.  Am I on the right direction, especially when passing through the CRAN check? Anyone has some hints on this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**(1) Pass caller's environment.** You can explicitly pass the parent environment and index into it.  Try this:

```
f2a <- function(P, env = parent.frame()) {
    env$calls <- env$calls + 1
    print(env$calls)
    return(P + env$c + env$d)
}

a <- 1
b <- 2
# same as f1 except f2 removed and call to f2 replaced with call to f2a
f1a <- function(){
    c <- 3
    d <- 4
    calls <- 0
    v <- vector()
    for(i in 1:10){
        v[i] <- f2a(P=0)
        c <- c+1
        d <- d+1
      }
     return(v)
}
f1a()
```

**(2) Reset called function's environment** We can reset the environment of `f2b` in `f1b` as shown here:

```
f2b <- function(P) {
    calls <<- calls + 1
    print(calls)
    return(P + c + d)
}

a <- 1
b <- 2
# same as f1 except f2 removed, call to f2 replaced with call to f2b
#  and line marked ## at the beginning is new
f1b <- function(){
    environment(f2b) <- environment() ##
    c <- 3
    d <- 4
    calls <- 0
    v <- vector()
    for(i in 1:10){
        v[i] <- f2b(P=0)
        c <- c+1
        d <- d+1
      }
     return(v)
}
f1b()
```

**(3) Macro using eval.parent(substitute(...))**  Yet another approach is to define a macro-like construct which effectively injects the body of `f2c` inline into `f1c1`.  Here `f2c` is the same as `f2b` except for the `calls <- calls + 1` line (no `<<-` needed) and the wrapping of the entire body in `eval.parent(substitute({...}))`.  `f1c` is the same as `f1a` except the call to `f2a` is replaced with a call to `f2c` .

```
f2c <- function(P) eval.parent(substitute({
    calls <- calls + 1
    print(calls)
    return(P + c + d)
}))

a <- 1
b <- 2
f1c <- function(){
    c <- 3
    d <- 4
    calls <- 0
    v <- vector()
    for(i in 1:10){
        v[i] <- f2c(P=0)
        c <- c+1
        d <- d+1
      }
     return(v)
}
f1c()
```

**(4) defmacro**  This is almost the same as the the last solution except it uses `defmacro` in the gtools package to define the macro rather than doing it ourself.  (Also see the Rcmdr package for another defmacro version.)  Because of the way `defmacro` works we must also pass `calls` but since it's a macro and not a function this just tells it to substitute `calls` in and is not the same as passing `calls` to a function.

```
library(gtools)

f2d <- defmacro(P, calls, expr = {
    calls <- calls + 1
    print(calls)
    return(P + c + d)
})

a <- 1
b <- 2
f1d <- function(){
    c <- 3
    d <- 4
    calls <- 0
    v <- vector()
    for(i in 1:10){
        v[i] <- f2d(P=0, calls)
        c <- c+1
        d <- d+1
      }
     return(v)
}
f1d()
```

Comment: This gives the result I want but I did not write clearly my request. In fact, I want to avoid to index all the variables passing into `f2`, i.e, not writing `env$`, that is why I tried to use `with`. I want to be able to modify the outside `calls` inside `f2` but not changing the other variables in the current environment. I will update the question.

Comment: It looks like just what I need. I will test it with my real case and update later. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would say that any variable that is needed inside a function should be passed on through its arguments. In addition, if its value is needed later you pass it back from the function. Not doing this can quite quickly lead to strange results, e.g. what if there are multiple functions defining a variable `x`, which one should be used. If the amount of variables is larger, you create a custom data structure for it, e.g. putting them into a named list.

Comment: I agree with you @Paul in general . I am trying to make my codes an R package but cannot pass through the CRAN check easily with many warnings like global variable bindings. There is many repeated code because the `f2` is defined inside a function and I want to use it in another new function. I realize that copy paste it is not a good option and can cause problems in later steps. I also want to reduce the effort because I don't want to change the already existing scrips too much. That's why I try to pass the environment instead of define a new data structure.

Answer (score 1):

One could also use a function that redefines other functions in the specified environment.

```
test_var <- "global"

get_test_var <- function(){
  return(test_var)
}

some_function <- function(){
  test_var <- "local"
  return(get_test_var()) 

}

some_function() # Returns "global". Not what we want here...

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

some_function2 <- function(){
  test_var <- "local"
  # define function locally
  get_test_var2 <- function(){
    return(test_var)
  }
  return(get_test_var2()) 
}

some_function2() # Returns "local", but 'get_test_var2' can't be used in other places.

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

add_function_to_envir <- function(my_function_name, to_envir) {
  script_text <- capture.output(eval(parse(text = my_function_name)))
  script_text[1] <- paste0(my_function_name, " <- ", script_text[1])
  eval(parse(text = script_text), envir = to_envir)
}

some_function3 <- function(){
  test_var <- "local"
  add_function_to_envir("get_test_var", environment()) 
  return(get_test_var()) 
}

some_function3() # Returns "local" and we can use 'get_test_var' from anywhere.
```

Here `add_function_to_envir(my_function_name, to_envir)` captures the script of the function, parses and reevaluates it in the new environment.

Note: the name of the function for `my_function_name` needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use nested functions and don't pass the variables on as arguments, but instead pass them on with `...`, I use the following function in all nested functions to get variables from the parent environment.

```
LoadVars <- function(variables, ...){
  for (var in 1:length(variables)) {
    v <- get(variables[var], envir = parent.frame(n=2))
    assign(variables[var], v, envir = parent.frame(n=1))
  }
}
```

Inside a nested function, I then `LoadVars(c("foo", "bar"))`.

This approach is useful in the sense that you only pass on the variables you need, similar as when you pass on the variables through arguments.

**Approach 2**

However, it is simple to rewrite this function to load in *all* variables from the parent function—or higher up if needed, just increase the `n` value in `parent.frame` from its original value of `2`.

```
LoadVars <- function(){
  variables <- ls(envir = parent.frame(n=2))

  for (var in 1:length(variables)) {
    v <- get(variables[var], envir = parent.frame(n=2))
    assign(variables[var], v, envir = parent.frame(n=1))
  }
}
```

---

**Example**

```
a <- 1

A <- function(...){
  b <- 2
  printf("A, a = %s", a)
  printf("A, b = %s", b)
  B()
}

B <- function(...){
  LoadVars()
  printf("B, a = %s", a)
  printf("B, b = %s", b)
}

A()
```

If you don't load variables in `B`, then `B` is able to load `a` because it is a global environment variable, but not `b` which is located in `A()`.

Output:

```
[1] "A, a = 1"
[1] "A, b = 2"
[1] "B, a = 1"
[1] "B, b = 2"
```