# R: attach all of the variables local to the function to global environment after it executes

Tags: r, function, global-variables, environment-variables, local-variables

Suppose I get some function from a client

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (x) {
    y <- 0
  } else {
    y <- 1
  }
}
```

Since I get it from a client I **cannot modify anything within f** (aka substitute <- with <<-, or explicitly attach variables to the global environment).

Is there a way to somehow access all of the variables created within f with whatever values got assigned to them (after I ran it) from the global environment ?
For example: if I ran

```
f(TRUE)
```

I would be able to access a variable "y" in the global environment and see that it is set to "0". I am not worried about overwriting anything in the global environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, pass in the parent environment:

```
f <- function(x, env = parent.frame()) {
  if (x) {
    env$y <- 0
  } else {
    env$y <- 1
  }
}
```

Option 2, use R's special assignment `<<-`

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (x) {
    y <<- 0
  } else {
    y <<- 1
  }
}
```

There's more options out there too. See topic: [In R, how to make the variables inside a function available to the lower level function inside this function?(with, attach, environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399205/in-r-how-to-make-the-variables-inside-a-function-available-to-the-lower-level-f)

Comment: Neither of these seem to fit OP's "*cannot modify anything within the function*" requirement...

Answer (score 0):

## 1. change the function

I have to believe that `deparse(f)` gives enough
information for defining a new identical function `g`.
With that in hand, we could tack on `print(ls())`
and other code for dumping local vars.

## 2. run the function unaltered

Ok, suppose we want to run `f` exactly as-is.
Let's see. In addition to argument `x`,
we also (implicitly) passed in an environment,
which `f` changes by creating a local `y` entry.

Define a *new* environment, a debugging variant,
which logs writes such as creation of `y`.
Have it report on those values in some convenient way,
such as by mirroring all writes to the global env.